# Background image severely slowing site down

Tags: wordpress, image, compression, wordpress-theming, background-image

I am currently customising my homepage on the Wordpress Avada theme.. However I have a very rich background image which is 18mb as a background. As a result the page runs really slowly, about 45 seconds to load for the homepage.

What is the way around this, how do i make the file smaller and how do the other websites do it?

All responses are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The answer of *the_dramatist* is good…Using a manipulation image tool of your choice, reduce your image **width** at between 1900 and 1200 pixels, with a **resolution of 72 dpi** and save it in JPEG format with a compression between 60% to 80% max… You have to make different tests to get a background image under 400 ko (lighter it will be, faster your web site will loads). The answer of the_dramatist is good… This way you will get a compromise between definition, weight and quality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to minimize your background image. 18 MB is too heavy for a website. Use Photoshop or any other image manipulation tool to reduce your image weight. And must reduce the weight below 300 KB. Otherwise your site will be very slow in future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is a detailed image with calligraphic patterns. Is it possible to reduce the file size without compromising too much on the quality.

Comment: Which format now your image is ? If it is `jpeg` it can be reduced. Or if it is in another format and after converting it to `jpeg` if you are satisfied with the quality then your image can be reduced to smaller weight. @M.Doe

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to minify a photo:

Use https://tinypng.com/ to get the size of your images smaller.
However, the picture may lose some of the quality during the process.

You could also host it in a CDN which is used for delivering content faster. 
read more about it here:
http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html

Try to use a file format that is usually smaller in size.
Read more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats

edit:
And yes, also Photoshop minimizing can help in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the size of the image with a width of 1920 OR a height of 1080, whichever is bigger.

Save the image as a JPG using 60% quality, file should be under 1MB. If you're using photoshop, save the image for web rather than save as.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using tools like photoshop and gimp you can use a plugin to automatically resize and compress all your images in bulk and the thumbnails generated by WordPress, here are some free plugin that I have found are doing a great job:

- [EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/) : Compress your images on your server using jpegtran, TinyJPG, JPEGmini, optipng, pngout, pngquant, TinyPNG, and gifsicle.
- [Imagify Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagify/) : Compress 25 MB a mouth of images on their server
- [Imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/) : Imsanity automatically resizes (not compress) huge image uploads.